# Rails 4: join queries with parent entity table, error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "states"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, inner-join

I have two entities built in a Rails 4 based web app:

```
class University
  belongs_to :state
end

class State
  has_many :universities
end
```

I am trying to create a query method that returns an array of universities for a given array of states.

**For example:**

For the states code: WA (Washington), OR (Oregon), CO (Colorado): `[WA, OR, CO]`, they should return the following universities:

```
University of Washington
University of Oregon
University of Colorado
....
```

I have this scope method written, but it does not work (see the error below):

```
universities.by_value_array(params[:state_codes])  # scope method by_value_array is defined in the University model

scope :by_value_array, -> (state_codes) {
  conditions = []
  q = ""
  state_codes.each_with_index { |code, i|
      if i == 0
        q = "universities.state_id = state.id and states.code = ?"
      else
        q += " OR universities.state_id = state.id and states.code = ?"
      end
      conditions.push(code.to_s)
    }
    conditions.insert(0, q)  # prepend

    joins(:state).where(conditions)
}
```

**Error message:**

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "state"
LINE 1: ...l_id" = $1 AND (universities.state_id = state...
                                                   ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "universities" INNER JOIN "states" ON "states"."id" = "universities"."state" WHERE "universities". (universities.state_id = state.id and state.code = 'WA' OR universities.state_id = state.id and state.code = 'CO')
```

**A http status of 422 - Unprocessable entity was thrown from this error.**

I am not sure how to make the joins query work in this situation, or is this even possible? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name should be `states` not `state`

```
if i == 0
  q = "universities.state_id = state.id and states.code = ?"
else
  q += " OR universities.state_id = state.id and states.code = ?"
end
```

Change the table name

```
if i == 0
  q = "universities.state_id = states.id and states.code = ?"
else
  q += " OR universities.state_id = states.id and states.code = ?"
end
```